# Need help with creating subliminal audio cd's with "Max/MSP'

Tags: software, mixing, home-studio

I have custom subliminal CD's scripts already made and masked under white noise and all I want to do is mix them together and record them realtime and maintain the right frequency level through the song for rthe subliminal to be effective.

Comment: I meant mix the already made subliminal message audio CD that is already under white noise to music

Comment: have you already downloaded the trial?

Comment: no not yet will do that today when I get home

Comment: Thanks I cant wait to get started. This weekend I will download install and do like you said and see what I am working with. Will post results and comments. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you get it installed, click on the Help tab up top and scroll down to "Max Tutorials" Read through those.  They explain a lot of stuff and can help you get on your feet quick to decide if this is the road you want to go.

After reading and going all the way through to 'simple math' copy the following onto your clipboard.  Click those 'open tutorial' links at the top of the tutorials.  They are priceless.

```
----------begin_max5_patcher----------
1153.3ocyX88aaaCD9Ym+JHz1CsnNBh52ZaX.MKEnAXKnOrtWZCFnkns4BEo
fjbbZKZ9aeGojbjSrkkaTDRP.o7oSj28ce2wS5amLwXl7VZgA5WPeBMYx2NY
xDsHkfI0+dhQJ41XNoPqlQrLMkJJMlVcuR5skZ4+1op+d67RZNJIWlkwDKPL
AhfLWStAIyQlD1bT4RVAZMiyQynvRQQwKowWSSLQn+dIoDUR47BPKJRN6+nw
knUhDXEYvcjnLN4Kln+TJuFoTET58TdFZNr3oxbJrcvkojRlTff++Twb0SbG
x9pFykyDv1tRns4fZgYjx3kf49u4vFVgEtdtlVSQ9VpQrW0jkioE5p5GRrJk
I3zRMpfqENWJJKXekpkYCOzFckqJaTtQJKQCbfedpcfQqUPPR0qfwayYDtg5
Fe+jSTCSehAIcL5ze2X+NNNxQ6qtdpIWrZz15Yyu8FG+dojmfRjqAZQllcPD
InXNK9ZzqzrGR7qUTzb1hkk02PoRAkq3fe1PlQEHSSSMg6yFJxnVzpLPOIvD
yARs.1AD8VfywDJ1+ZEgFn6KjpeIAYJNaAEoS5L2Imze+gFmPcjwInhS5qlB
id1BMNiSn47bxhGVjXNiSQ.lRq4qcQXczIpAQZPIx9YluhGVPoTtXAm1k2En
yC8ztm6lwt8tsciFoUhJ+RFsZoMXJF2UO1IwQ+HthftFd3GEdKQXDuQZrjKy
q1cHD4FX4EMEtJB3z1dsuB2xE2ApX6nQEruN163LfAc6tPqoHiciXCb468fk
u4tgFHc8pJlTUz+P.o8w.j6k1UvVH.XYm3n+vhiqfJNq1.ifIT2oSWPhmutv
JNvsEE6HIWXSuHObXS+ErRZZ8NaLmTn4QuRHUSyHbNqnjEW7Z0OmpF9mOt4x
yu3RXxEBjtV9pm5h28GJ4e3C+kZRipv7EWL69G+ryzprWUI2q5kx7DVbWZeu
tu6LsYcNaAqrc3a6ntygRe1JEhSlQ45SaaCksIDCb+AozhBxB5ixrRkITzOi
MNHsv1R2JX0gu3viJS4ArhdltryDknAtdypzYzbiCVmvNR62UsC+zxINtpty
HhE6DHbBGVjfSugxSovKwbWOfC6pigr0MlopT7rdtrq0P12UxYcw1sBqh2US
NCc7dGsV4hGkyPyxoPe6I5t2G91R7a0gdn2.1VxwUdXfSJneMgDeWmcoVkO3
T0fpWyX2EGOHkHX.i6a9T.CcPutCcLt58PrGvVnbNPKTSae0dKQZ2AYn9NEj
aZV5e5R8xVgV0mXaqpwYE4CdlU8Y3+JrU+.AG0GFR8xcc0S1LnoDZ91gmosF
5WRX02uAaoCNJ54wTZ1dKSQIIbSH5wYf68sBZSe0JneU+G701ztfR91vVgbU
dbyVz7NFn68hDJz0nP+otZqTzVJsjkjPEsytRYIYR3.lMf9NChGkMgOfMYOp
lTXePofwEkh5gMMtnjcePI+Q2jv8wjviWfyuGvDzU1XBSOX61sM4DNtDbudX
SiakonWdQNbOLovWbUABdwUDH3ITC.9w2O4+ADAKPtC
-----------end_max5_patcher-----------
```

That's just a really basic patch to show you how you can have basic volume metering of a track you desire.  Click File->New Patcher and then just apple+v (cntrl+v windows right?) and you will see a patch.

I highly recommend their official forums as well because there are incredibly smart people over there dedicated to Max.

http://cycling74.com/forums/

Get back to us =)

Comment: any updates for us?